# Can I Apply Multiple Properties of the Z Transform Simultaneously?

Tags: z-transform

Using the time shifting, time reversal, and scaling, I want to derive the **form** of the Z Transform of

$$x[n]=-a^n u[-(n+1)]$$

$u[n]$ is the discrete-time **unit step** function:

$$ u[n] \triangleq \begin{cases}
0 \qquad & n < 0 \\
1 \qquad & n \ge 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

**(disregarding the ROC)**

given the Z transform of the unit step:

$$ U(z) = \mathcal{Z} \Big\{u[n] \Big\} = \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}} $$

---

Let $X(z)$ be informally, the **expected form** of the Z Transform that $x[n]$ will be taking:

Using the time reversal property

$$ X(z) = U(z^{-1}) $$

Applying the time shifting property:

$$ X(z) = z^{1}U(z^{-1}) $$

Then, by scaling

$$ X(z) = zU(a^{-1}z^{-1}) $$

Returning to the Z Transform of $x[n]$

$$\begin{align}
 \mathcal{Z} \Big\{-a^nu[-(n+1)] \Big\} &= -zU(a^{-1}z^{-1}) \\
 & \Longrightarrow \frac{-z}{1-az} \\
\end{align}$$

which is not the correct answer

$$ \frac{1}{1-az^{-1}} $$

Please note that I momentarily disregarded the concern for ROC in order to know if I can stack the three properties together to solve for the form of the Z Transform (similar to how I apply multiple properties of the Laplace and Fourier Transform Simultaneously)

Comment: When you apply scaling, $a^n x[n] \leftrightarrow X(z/a)$, but you didn't include the $a^{-1}$ outside G.

Comment: @Juancho I'm sorry but I didn't exactly got what you meant by $a^{-1}$ outside $G(z)$. Are you referring to the $a^n$ of $f(n)$? It vanished after applying the scaling property

Comment: they are actually the same answer.  except for a minus sign.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson look again -- his answer has a pole at $z = 1/a$, the "correct" answer has a pole at $z = a$.

Comment: Thank You for all your help. I finally understood what you meant by $a^{-1}$ outside $G(z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following answer for $$
X(z)=\mathcal{Z} \Big\{-a^nu[-(n+1)] \Big\}
$$
given
$$
U(z) = \mathcal{Z} \Big\{u[n] \Big\} = \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}
$$

---

Let

$$
\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}(z)
$$
denote the transformation stages under which each property applies

Using the time reversal property

$$ X_1(z) = U(z^{-1}) $$

Applying the time shifting property:

$$ X_2(z) =z^1X_1= z^{1}U(z^{-1}) $$

Then, by scaling

$$ X_3(z) = X_2(a^{-1}z)=a^{-1}zU(az^{-1}) $$

Returning to the Z Transform of $x[n]$

$$\begin{align}
 \mathcal{Z} \Big\{-a^nu[-(n+1)] \Big\} &= -X_3(z) \\
 & \Longrightarrow \frac{-za^{-1}}{1-a^{-1}z} \\
\end{align}$$

which after simplification finally agrees with the correct answer

$$ \frac{1}{1-az^{-1}} $$

---

It loosely concludes that I can use multiple properties of the Z Transform as long that each transformation stages is consistent (e.g. $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$).

It is now left to determine if the properties also applies simultaneously with the ROC like how the form of the Z Transform did.